# How to build a generic menu component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to build a menu screen component that can be used later on easily. The component only has options in a list way.

```
    const options = [
  {
    text: 'Option 1',
  },
  {
    text: 'Option 2',
  },
  {
    text: 'Option 3',
  },
];
```

and I just map it inside the component.

```
const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {options.map((option, index) => (
        <MenuOption text={option.text} index={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const MenuOption = ({ text, index }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So anyone can use this menu component by passing in the options data. What i want is for this component to also run functions corresponding to the option clicked. So we can easily pass the function that needs to be run as a prop to the  component. The main question is that **how do i relate/map the options with the corresponding function?**

***NOTE: I can't send the functions with the options data object in the props.***

Comment: I can pass the function as a prop but don't know how to relate it to the particular option. I can't pass the function as a key: value in the "options" data object though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you can just send one callback to the `Menu` component:

```
const Menu = ({ onOptionClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {options.map((option, index) => (
        <MenuOption text={option.text} index={index} onClick={onOptionClick} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const MenuOption = ({ text, index, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => { onClick(index, text, whatever) }}>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't this run the same function for all three options?

Comment: It would, but with different parameters, so you would differentiate it by the index passed to the callback

Comment: You can either pass one callback and do that, or pass a different callback to each option element in the `options` prop

Comment: How would someone use this component according to the first/index case you mentioned. Just by using <Menu/> once we can only pass one function right?

Comment: You can pass as many things through props as the component needs.

Comment: So sending all three functions in order through one onClick prop?

Comment: `<Menu onOptionClick={handleOptionClicked} />` `function handleOptionClicked(index) { console.log(\`Option number ${index} was clicked\`);} `